# How to read string by id from windows library like winapi LoadString on linux

Tags: linux, windows, winapi, dll

I have some strings like "@%SystemRoot%\System32\sensrsvc.dll,-1001" which I know represent a certain string in the dll file.
On windows, I can use LoadLibrary to load the dll and then use LoadString to read the string with id 1001 from the dll.
ButI need to copy the windows dll and related strings from the windows device to the linux server and analyze it on the linux server,, is there any way?

Comment: You'll need to read and interpret the [Portable Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) file format, and once you've located the `.rsrc` section, locate and interpret the [string table format](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813).

Answer (score 0):

> But I now have to analyze these strings with their associated dlls on linux, is there any way?

**First of all**, you have to understand how string tables in Windows work and why they are used:

In Windows, a string can be located directly in the code: If you write the following code:

```
const char * example = "Hello world!";
```

... the string is **not** stored in the string table and you cannot access it using `LoadString()`.

Programmers of a DLL must explicitly put a string into the string table if the string shall be accessible using `LoadString()`.

Normally, a programmer does this if the program shall be translated to another language later on because a string in the string table can be replaced without re-compiling the entire program.

So when the string is located in the string table, the program can be translated without re-compiling it.

Strings that will not be translated are put "directly" into the program so they are not accessible using `LoadString()`.

**Under Linux**, such strings (that shall be translated) are not even stored in the file corresponding to the EXE or DLL file in Windows, but they are stored in a **separate** file.

Many of these files use the binary `.mo` format (used by the `gettext` library), others use the ASCII `.po` format.

So if you want to analyze the strings of the `vlc` media player (as an example), you don't have to analyze the file `/usr/bin/vlc` but the file `/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo` if you want to see the German language strings and `/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/vlc.mo` if you are interested in the French language strings.

> to copy the windows dll

... and you want to write a **Linux** program that reads strings from a **Windows** DLL file?

In **older** Windows DLL/EXE files, the strings read by `LoadString()` were stored directly in the DLL or EXE file.

In **newer** Windows files, it is done similar to Linux: The strings are stored in a separate file named `.mui`.

Example: The German language strings of `mlang.dll` are stored in `C:\Windows\System32\de-DE\mlang.dll.mui`; the German language strings for `...\iexplore.exe` are stored in `...\de-DE\iexplore.exe.mui`.

So if you want to read the strings from a "new" DLL or EXE file, you must copy the ".mui" file to your Linux machine and not the "actual" DLL file.

`.mui` files themselves seem to be DLL files, and they always seem to be 32-bit DLL files (even if the corresponding DLL or EXE file is a 64-bit DLL or EXE file).

Just like Windows does not have any functions for reading Linux files, Linux does not have any functions for Windows files.

So you'll have to write a function for parsing DLL/EXE files yourself. It is not very difficult, however, it is a lot of work...

(... especially if you want to support both 32- and 64-bit DLL files.)

An alternative could be using `wine`: `wine` is a program suite that allows you to run (many, but not all) Windows programs on Linux. Maybe your Windows program (that calls `LoadString()`) works using `wine`.

Comment: I mean I need to copy the windows dll and related strings from the windows device to the linux server and analyze it on the linux server, is there any way?